# Why isn't my function called after DOMContentLoaded?

Tags: javascript, svg

Ive created this jFiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/t5Lgwvzg/5/

I have a function that changes the colours of a few svg polygons I've made. When I run this locally with Chrome/Firefox, the colours load as expected. But when I run it with Internet Explorer/JSFiddle the polygons remain white they're original colour. My question is why isn't this working? I've spent hours trying to figure it out . . .

Here's my function:

```
function statColor() {

    var random;
    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = "Enter";

    for (var i = 0; i < counties.length; i++) {

        random = (Math.random() * 100);
        elem = document.getElementById(counties[i]);

        if (random >= 0 && random <= 25) {

            elem.style.fill = "green";
        } else if (random > 25 && random <= 50) {

            elem.style.fill = "yellow";
        } else if (random > 50 && random <= 75) {

            elem.style.fill = "orange";
        } else if (random > 75 && random <= 100) {

            elem.style.fill = "red";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("polyNorthernIreland").style.fill = "grey";
}
```

And this is where it should be called:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", statColor, false);
```

Should have also mentioned I'm using IE11

Comment: Do you observe this problem in < IE 9? See compatibility for `addEventListener`. Seems like browser compatibility issue for < IE 9. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @RexOverflow I thought it might be something like that, but couldn't find anything definite. So this should work with IE11 then?

Comment: Instead of using DOMContentLoaded why not put your script just before the closing body tag or use `window.load = statColor`. It should work in IE 11. IDK I always put my scripts just before the closing body tag.

Comment: @RexOverflow Because then it won't even start loading your script until it has parsed through all images and CSS files in the document, and because it has no semantic meaning inside the `<body>` structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `attachEvent()` , `addEventListener()` doesn't work on IE less than 9.0

Comment: Should have mentioned I'm using IE11, edited my post.